# Java Socket Server won't process second client

Tags: java, sockets

I've got a client and server coded in Java, once the server has received one message from the client, the server stops receiving all new messages. No errors are thrown when the client tries to sent more messages. I can't seem to find out why it doesn't allow or receive new connections! Please help.

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {

    ServerSocket echoServer = null;
    String line;
    DataInputStream is;
    PrintStream os;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    boolean Listening = true;

    int sPort = 9999;
    // Try to open a server socket on port 9999

   try {
       echoServer = new ServerSocket(sPort);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }   
// Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept 
// connections.
// Open input and output streams

while (Listening){
        try {
            clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
            is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            //os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

      // As long as we receive data, echo that data back to the client.

            while (true) {
              line = is.readLine();

              if(line != null){
              //os.println(line); 
             log(Level.SEVERE, "New connection to server {0}", line);

            }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: If the line read is null, break from while loop

Comment: There is no crash here, just an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (true) 
{
              line = is.readLine();

              if(line != null){
              //os.println(line); 
             log(Level.SEVERE, "New connection to server {0}", line);

            }
 }
```

after accepting a connection it is entering into this infinite loop.due to this loop it will never accept new connection.

> to solve this issues, start new thread each time when new client comes, pass socket connection of the client and read data from that client.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues as below:

---

```
while (true) {
              line = is.readLine();

              if(line != null){
              //os.println(line); 
             log(Level.SEVERE, "New connection to server {0}", line);

            }
```

Here you need to break after reading the content from the Socket irrespective of whether you read in different thread or same.

---

You need to declare `boolean Listening` to `volatile` else the server wont stop.

Answer (score 0):

while (true) {
              line = is.readLine();

```
          if(line != null){
          //os.println(line); 
         log(Level.SEVERE, "New connection to server {0}", line);

        }
        }
```

the code will block new request, so the second request will not be accepted.
I make an example accounding to your code. Hope it help to you.
The Server Class will only be userd to accept socket connection and create a new thread to process it.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        ServerSocket echoServer = null;
        boolean listening = true;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        int sPort = 9999;
        // Try to open a server socket on port 9999

        try {
            echoServer = new ServerSocket(sPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept
        // connections.
        // Open input and output streams

        while (listening) {
            try {
                clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
                System.out.println("receive new connection");
                new ProcessClientThread(clientSocket).start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                        null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ProcessClientThread Class extends Thread Class and defined a constructor with a Socket type parameter. Override run method of it. The run method get input stream from socket and print it out. When it accept 0, it will close the scoket connection. Its code like this

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ProcessClientThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket = null;

    public ProcessClientThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DataInputStream is;
        String line;

        boolean flag = true;
        try {
            is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (flag) {
                line = is.readLine();

                if (Integer.valueOf(line) != 0) {
                    // os.println(line);
                    // Logger.getLogger(Level.SEVERE,
                    // "New connection to server {0}", line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                } else {

                    Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    w.write(0);
                    w.flush();

                    flag = false;
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("close a connection");
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

There is a StartUp Class which used to start up the server thread.

```
public class StartUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Server()).start();
    }

}
```

Run the below Client Class to test the Server.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        Reader serverReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
        boolean flag = true;
        while(flag) {
            int readContent = reader.read();
            writer.write(readContent);
            writer.flush();

            if(readContent == 0) {
                writer.close();
                client.close();
                flag = false;
            }
        }

    }

}
```